# Problems with windows interface

Tags: 14.04, unity, gui, window-manager, window

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity for a year. Everything was OK until update last month. After it some program windows became a mess, just like on this screenshot.
[image]

How can I fix this?

UPD. I've noticed, this happens only to KDE-based apps. Like KolourPaint, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I've solved the problem myself by removing **`.kde`** folder. Yes, it's full solution.

Comment: Okay, can you explain how did that solve it? Has the system created the .kde folder again?
If yes, then I suppose if it happens again could you rename the folder so as to keep both copies(erroneous and correct) for analysis?

Comment: Some settings were damaged during update, I think. Yes, .kde will be created every time when GUI starts, is there are KDE libs in your OS. No I cannot give you and old copy, because I've deleted it.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for telling. If it happens again, please send the damaged files somehow(as a .zip). That would be an interesting study.

Comment: Are you KDE developer?

Comment: Nope. I'm just a programming student who looks at the source code of stuff he uses. If its a bug that I can reproduce and fix, I'd love to do that.

Comment: That's post hoc ergo propter hoc reasoning. It is very very unlikely that deleting the .kde folder had anything to do with fixing the display of virtualbox-qt from the screenshot. Virtualbox is not even a KDE application. It just uses the same underlying library, qt. An update of virtualbox was release on Nov 25 for ubuntu 14.04. It is much more likely that the update fixed your display.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you had NVidia or AMD drivers installed manually? You would need to reinstall them now. When I once updated my system Xorg stopped working, and I had to reinstall NVidia drivers (the same way, i.e. manually, i.e. by NVidia's installer). Maybe in your case it's slightly different, Xorg works but configuration is messed up.

Comment: No, I haven't. It's office PC with Intel HD graphics.